# Why does adding float:left to my css make my link unclickable?

Tags: css, hyperlink, css-float

I have a view with a section defined thus:

```
<div id="QuestionBody">
        <p><%=ViewData.Model.Body %></p>
        <div id="QuestionEditLink"><%=Html.ActionLink ("Edit","EditQuestion","Question",new {id=Model.QuestionId},null) %></div>
        <div id="QuestionHistoryLink"><%=Html.ActionLink ("History","ShowHistory","Question",new {postId=Model.PostId,questionId=Model.QuestionId},null) %></div>  
        <div id="AnsweringUser"><a href="/Profile/Profile?userName=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawnZ6IhK1C5cf_9wKstNNfSYIdnRp_zryW4">Answered by Sam</a></div>          
    </div>
```

and this produces a section with some text and a couple of links under it.  I wanted the links to be next to each other.  I'm new to css and web development but added this to my style sheet:

```
#QuestionEditLink
{
    color: #666666;
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    padding:2px;
}

#QuestionHistoryLink
{
    color: #666666;
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    padding:2px;
}
```

and hey presto the links were nicely aligned.  unfortunately they are also not clickable and in fact the cursor doesn't change when moving over them either.

So what did i do wrong?  how to I use the css to align the two links next to each other so they are still clickable?

EDIT:

This behaviour is in chrome 8.0.552.215 and in firefox 3.6.  It works as I would expect in IE 8, annoyingly.

EDIT2:

I have added the page to JSBin : http://jsbin.com/odefa4/edit  which shows the issue.  Only the question is styled and shows the problem, the links for the answers work ok...

Comment: could you link to the page so we can see the problem in action, might be easier to find a solution for you :)

Comment: Does this happen in every browser? Why are you using a div instead of a Span if you want them next to each other? I just checked this and it works fine on Chrome and IE8, is that all your markup?

Comment: @Treemonkey, its not live anywhere, only on my dev machine, so unfortunately no I can't link to it...

Comment: could u atleast add the HTML n CSS snippet to JSBin?

Comment: @Shree, @Treemonkey I have added a link to JSBin which shows the issue (Thanks for pointing out JSBin shree, didn't know that existed)

Comment: fyi you dont really need to use div element around the link! as really there is not a reason for this.. just bloating code right? I often attempt to use the minimum markup to achieve a layout doing so I find helps in future :>

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The usual reason is that there's a transparent layer on top. It's normally caused when a box is wider than you think and has a transparent border/padding. Use CSS to apply a temporary border to all items and you'll check whether it's the case.

**Update #1**

```
div, span, p{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**Update #2**

I can see that `#QuestionEditLink` and `#QuestionHistoryLink` are floating. That means that they no longer use space in the page flow. So when you display `#AskingUser` next it starts at the same point and, being the last one on the page, it gets displayed on top of the two other boxes.

Your layout appears to be fully vertical. I presume you don't need any `float: left` at all.

*BTW, you have lots of duplicate IDs.*

Comment: This sounds like a plan.  As I said I'm new to all this so how to I add something to the CSS which adds a border to all items?

Comment: Thanks Alvaro, I see the problem now (I have updated my post to show some more of the view), and it seems that it is the AnsweringUser div is in the way.  now how to fix...

Comment: Yeah I assume that i really need to change my div ids to div class instead.  Doing some of this stuff for the first time and was playing on the train yesterday with no internet.  I want them to flow, but without the float they always seem to go one below the other and the div with the links don't seem to have individual lines around them.  Thanks for the help.  You've given me soemthing to go on, and other useful pointers

Comment: Block level elements (`<p>`, `<div>`...) expand horizontally by default. Inline elements (`<a>`, `<span>`...) don't. You don't need to do anything special to place links side by side; just don't wrap them in separate block level tags. It also helps to use an HTML validator.

Comment: I love this div, span, p tip!! Like seeing the matrix.

Answer (score 81):

The fix is pretty simple and cross browser too, add this (to your unclickable link):

```
#QuestionEditLink, #QuestionHistoryLink {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

The fix here is the `z-index`, but it won't work if `position` isn't relative/absolute/fixed.

For more info on `z-index` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Have used this all the time, is simple, works in **all** browsers (IE6+, FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera).

Since others already said about your CSS issues there, I won't add to it. Just providing a solution, by the way, tested it with your provided JSBin, worked as always!

Comment: Technically this might work, but (I admit I don't know that much about html/web development) but this feels hacky to me.  Maybe its not, but it sets my teeth on edge, like I've got cotton wool in my mouth.  My problem seems to be that I'm using unsuitable elements for my link containers.  Interesting reading though.

Comment: This is the answer, works great, thank you VERY VERY MUCH!

Comment: Wow, how *obvious*.  :-)  CSS voodoo to the rescue.  Works perfectly.

Comment: This is *very* awesome solution. You know that `label` element passes clicks to an `input` element when we wrap it around the input (not working for single line float row) or use `for` attribute. On mobile, I love wrapping inputs that way because I can made the label bigger than the input - and it simplifies tapping to the input. I'm using `margin: -100%` and `padding-right: 100%` on a `label` element. But it has a drawback: it covers all the floating elements on the right side of the row. Your solution is the only one which works there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42542011/84661

Comment: This answer is 12 years old - and it still works. One button on a 14 year old Rails app running on a client's intranet stopped working in 08/2022. This coincided with the move to a new server, but can now also be seen in docker container running this app. position: relative and z-index to the rescue. I am shocked, but this worked! thank you

Answer (score 2):

hmmm sounds like a simple bug often found with multiple floats, you could try adding a clearing element after the links i would use something like

```
<b class="clear"></b>

.clear{
float:none;
clear:both;
font-size:0px;
line-height:0px;
height:0px;
}
```

that should be fairly cross browser, you may need to add   inside so its

```
<b class="clear">&nbsp;</b>
```

Comment: Thank you, Treemonkey. I'm surprised your solution hasn't received more votes. It's so quick & easy.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will be invalid as you are using IDs when this should be a job for classes. This will do what you want:

```
#AskingUser {
    border: none;
    float: right;
    width:auto;
    padding: 2px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
}
```

and add

```
#QuestionBody {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I've left it as IDs but you should adjust all your CSS and HTML so that they are classes instead

`.askingUser {}` and `<div class="askingUser"></div>`

if that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Ross I'll try this.  Yeah I've realised that my ids should be classes.

Comment: Whilst as an answer this works, I have marked @Alvaro's as the accepted answer as I learnt a lot more about what I was doing wrong from that.  Cheers for the pointers though, it was most useful.