# CSS alignment problem

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I make my registration fields like this

[image]

How can I achieve this via CSS?
I mean, that my textboxes should be aligned from label's end to the page's end...

EDIT

Here is my view part

```
<div id="member-search">

<h5>Last Name:</h5>
@Html.TextBox("member-last-name")
</div>
<div>
<h5>Pass:</h5>
@Html.TextBox("member-pass")
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Search" class="button"/>
</div>
```

In CSS I tried a lot, but with no success. width:auto doesn't help and I don't find solution for this. Thanks for help.

Comment: Give the `<h5>`s a fixed width, or put the whole thing in a table. There is no way that I know of to 1) have equal widths, 2) let the width be fluid and 3) not use a table all at the same time.

Comment: @Jon I don't want fixed width... I want the opposite.

Comment: This isn't the right code, if you want help with an input, show us code for a rendered input.

Comment: What is wrong here? I use Razor, which converts Html.Textbox to <input type="text"/>...

So, which CSS I should give to that inputs?

Comment: just use jQuery to dynamically process the width, you have listed jQuery as a tag!

Comment: Why is a question about CSS tagged with "jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3"? And why can't I retag that question, but may retag any other question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With changes to your view you can achieve this. My answer is based on the following answer: [How to make text input box to occupy all the remaining width within parent block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825861/how-to-make-text-input-box-to-occupy-all-the-remaining-width-within-parent-block/5825975#5825975)

You can look at the modified version of the answer at http://jsfiddle.net/626B2/63/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="inner">
        <label>UserName</label><span><input id="text" type="text" /></span>
    </div>
    <div id="inner">
        <label>pass</label><span><input id="text" type="text" /></span>
    </div>
    <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#inner {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
label {
    display: table-cell;
    white-space:nowrap;

}
span {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 10px;
}
#text {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer..
And how can I achieve that label's text staying inline? If write "User Name" instead "UserName" second part will go to next line))))

Comment: whitespace:nowrap solved this problem too... Thank man for the answer)))

Comment: @mesiesta: Note that this answer [won't work in IE7](http://caniuse.com/css-table), if that matters.

Comment: I know, I'm writing site using html 5, so IE 9+ supporting is enough...

But your answer is good too, I vote up for it)))

Comment: Nice! But those `id="inner"` and `id="text"` should really be `class="inner"` and `class="text"`, and the corresponding CSS should use `.inner` and `.text` instead of `#inner` and `#text`.

Answer (score 2):

After I had to refator your HTML to properly reflect the actual rendered code, this is the best I can come up with.

HTML:

```
<div id="member-search">

<label for="member-last-name">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="member-last-name" class="myInput">
</div>
<div class="clear">
<label for="member-pass">Pass:</label>
<input type="text" name="member-pass" class="myInput">
</div>

<div class="clear">
<input type="submit" value="Search" class="button"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#member-search
{
    width: 100%;
}

label
{
    float: left;
}

.myInput
{
    float: right;
    width: 88%;/*MILES AN HOUR, MARTY!*/
}

.clear
{
    clear: both;
}
```

[Check here for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/SxuUX/).

Comment: Well, that is fixed width again…

Comment: What? 88 %?

My textboxes begin point must be end point of span... In your example all textbxoes starts from the same point..
Take a look at my screenshot again...

Comment: I understand your needs, but it's very difficult to do this. If you se the width to 100%; the inputs will float to a new line. This is the only viable way I can think of to closely reproduce your desires at this moment.

Answer (score 2):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/edGAp/

This works in IE7 and greater + all modern browsers.

**CSS:**

```
#member-search label {
    float: left
}
#member-search span {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 4px
}
#member-search input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="member-search">
    <div>    
        <label for="member-last-name">Last Name:</label>
        <span><input type="text" name="member-last-name" /></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="member-pass">Pass:</label>
        <span><input type="text" name="member-pass" /></span>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="button" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go

http://jsfiddle.net/8YAhW/

Pay attention to the label tag and the "for" attribute. This helps when tabbing across items commonly used when making forms.

Hope this helps you out

Comment: In this example the input fields do not span to the end of the page.

Comment: My question isn't about it... Watch again to my screenshot... My two textboxes ends in the same point(div's end)...